# What is the proper way to create a Release version of my C++ library on GitHub?

Tags: c++, git, github, release, release-management

I am maintaining a scientific library as a C++ repository on GitHub, using Cmake for builds.

Now the problem is the following:

There is a lot of code in the repository that the end users **do not want to download**. This includes e.g. support code to produce precomputed coefficients and calculation parameters. The end users only want to download the minimal amount of files that are necessary for them to do their job. The motivation for this is to minimize the size of the library and to make it easier for the end users to understand the code they want to use.

My question is:
Is it possible to create a "Release Version" of a library in a GitHub repository, and if yes, how should this be done properly?

Comment: Just put a big comment in the file(s) "Do not change!".  Also, if it's on GitHub, isn't one of the things anyone would like to do is actually *experiment* with the code, even the code you say shouldn't be "tampered with"?  If the person using the code wants to tamper with it and were warned, let them go ahead.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have reformulated the question to make it clear that it is not the main motivation to keep the users from modifying the code, but to just deliver them the code that they want. There must be a misunderstanding here because your comment is not helpful at all. This is also probably more of a git question, and less C++.

Comment: I shared that misunderstanding, so that's at least three of the people trying to help you who read your situation that way. Going back over it I can see what you were trying to convey in it now, now that you've got the disambiguated version up.  One of the things that comes with more experience is seeing more possibilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add .gitattributes to your repository, you can add files/wildcards in similar fashion as in .gitignore but then you can add `export-ignore` after the file entry. Files that then match these ignored patterns wont be added to the release source archive.